# In Java, how can I draw on a JPanel using data from another class?

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way to draw on a JPanel using data from another class? Here is the code I tried:

```
class overlay extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g, lineStore data) {        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            g.drawLine(data[i].x1,data[i].y1,data[i].x2,data[i].y2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to pass that data to the panel via some other method and trigger a repaint.  You could use a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Comment: Try and think about how the API already does this, for example, `setBackground`

Comment: If I moved the array into the overlay class and did something like frame.redraw() in the right place, would that do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class overlay extends JPanel {

private lineStore data;

public overlay(lineStore data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {        
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        g.drawLine(data[i].x1,data[i].y1,data[i].x2,data[i].y2);
    }
}
```

}

To use it do:

```
lineStore data; //create lineStore here
overlay panel = new overlay(data);
panel.repaint();
```